python,SIRモデルを使用した感染力等の推定
実データに関して、SIRモデルにフィッティングをし、感染率と回復率を推定しようとしたのですが、うまくいかず、それぞれの値が10か0のみとなってしまいました。
以下がそのコードです。
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('Tokyo.csv')

# Convert the date column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Define the periods for each wave
waves = {
    'Wave 1': ('2020-01-01', '2020-05-31'),
    'Wave 2': ('2020-06-01', '2020-10-31'),
    'Wave 3': ('2020-11-01', '2021-03-31'),
    'Wave 4': ('2021-04-01', '2021-06-30'),
    'Wave 5': ('2021-07-01', '2021-10-31'),
    'Wave 6': ('2021-11-01', '2022-03-31'),
    'Wave 7': ('2022-04-01', '2022-09-26')  # Data up to 2022/09/26
}

# SIR model differential equations
def sir_model(y, t, alpha, beta):
    S, I, R = y
    dSdt = -alpha * S * I
    dIdt = alpha * S * I - beta * I
    dRdt = beta * I
    return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt

# Function to fit the SIR model
def fit_sir_model(data, population):
    I0 = data[0]
    R0 = 0
    S0 = population - I0 - R0
    y0 = S0, I0, R0
    t = np.arange(len(data))

    def loss(params):
        alpha, beta = params
        solution, infodict = odeint(sir_model, y0, t, args=(alpha, beta), full_output=True, rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-6)
        I = solution[:, 1]
        return np.mean((I - data) ** 2)

    result = minimize(loss, [0.1, 0.1], bounds=[(0, 10), (0, 10)])
    alpha, beta = result.x
    return alpha, beta

# Population size
population = 13000000

# Calculate alpha and beta for each wave and plot the results
for wave, (start_date, end_date) in waves.items():
    wave_data = df[(df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)]
    cases = wave_data['Positive Cases'].values / population
    alpha, beta = fit_sir_model(cases, population)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(wave_data['Date'], wave_data['Positive Cases'], marker='o', linestyle='-')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Positive Cases')
    plt.title(f'{wave} Positive Cases\nalpha: {alpha:.4f}, beta: {beta:.4f}')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
    print(f'{wave} - alpha: {alpha}, beta: {beta}')

説明
読み込んでいるcsvファイルは東京における感染者数の推移が書かれています。
第一波～第七波に分けてそれぞれの感染率と回復率を求めています。このコードを用いて求めた結果は
Wave 1 - alpha: 9.999999999999918, beta: 10.0
Wave 2 - alpha: 10.0, beta: 10.0
Wave 3 - alpha: 0.0, beta: 10.0
Wave 4 - alpha: 10.0, beta: 10.0
Wave 5 - alpha: 10.0, beta: 10.0
Wave 6 - alpha: 9.999999999524068, beta: 10.0
Wave 7 - alpha: 9.999999999820693, beta: 10.0

です。

もし可能であれば、使用しているCSVファイルを公開するか、その入手先の情報を出していただいた方が回答が付きやすいかと思います（プログラムをそのまま試せるようになるので）。

データのソースはこのサイトです。https://catalog.data.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/dataset/t000055d0000000389/resource/24759a22-149a-4d0b-aa24-944f901c1c2e　このデータに関して発症＿年月日の部分をDateに、陽性者数の部分をPositive Casesにしています

質問のコードはご自身で書かれたものでしょうか？計算式が合っていることは確認済でしょうか？

Pythonと実例で学ぶ微分方程式という本に載っていたコードを使って書いています

(1) S, I, R は1に規格化するのですか？しないのですか？(2)比較し得るものでフィットしていますか？このデータの「陽性者数」とは何を意味しているのでしょう？

(1)するつもりで書いてます。(2)その日陽性だと判定されている人の総人数という認識です。
